# how to ignore extra kwargs in python-attrs class

Tags: python, python-attrs

For example:

```
@attrs
class Foo:
  a = attrib()

f = Foo(a=1, b=2)
```

Code above will throw an error because class `Foo` doesn't have `b` attr. But I want to discard passed `b` value as if I just called `f = Foo(a=1)`. In my use case I have dynamic dict (which I want to transform into attr-class) and I simply do not need some of the keys.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out a more elegant solution which allows you to take advantage of the features of **attrs** while also tweaking the `__init__` logic. See [attrs documentation](https://www.attrs.org/en/latest/init.html#hooking-yourself-into-initialization) for more info.

```
@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, auto_detect=True)
class Foo():
    a: int
    optional: int = 3

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
      filtered = {
        attribute.name: kwargs[attribute.name]
        for attribute in self.__attrs_attrs__
        if attribute.name in kwargs
      }
      self.__attrs_init__(**filtered)
```

The code above allows you to specify extraneous keyword args. It also allows for optional args.

```
>>> Foo(a = 1, b = 2)
Foo(a=1, optional=3)
```

**attrs** detects the explicit init method (due to `auto_detect=True`) and still creates the init function, but calls it `__attrs_init__`. This allows you do define your own init function to do preprocessing and then call `__attrs_init__` when you are done.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print(inspect.getsource(Foo.__attrs_init__))
def __attrs_init__(self, a, optional=attr_dict['optional'].default):
    self.a = a
    self.optional = optional
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
class FromDictMixin:
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data: dict):
        return cls(**{
            a.name: data[a.name]
            for a in cls.__attrs_attrs__
        })

@attrs
class Foo(FromDictMixin):
    a = attrib()
```

It works, but it looks kinda ugly. I was hopping that `attrs` lib had out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more of a question of serialization/deserialization/validation and attrs is quite strict on its argument for multiple reasons. One of them is typing (as in types, not pressing keys :)) and the other is robustness/debugabiity. Ignoring arguments that you might have just misspelt can lead to very frustrating moments. It's better to move this kind of stuff into a separate layer.

You can find some possible tools for that in https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/wiki/Extensions-to-attrs.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar but I didn't want to write a custom `__init__` method for every class.  So I created a decorator where it would attach an `__init__` method to the class **before** instantiation then wrap in `attrs.define` decorator.

This is just an example but does what you want.

```
import attrs


def define(cls):
    def __init__(cls, **kwargs):
        filtered = {}
        for attr in cls.__attrs_attrs__:
            if attr.name in kwargs:
                filtered[attr.name] = kwargs[attr.name]
        cls.__attrs_init__(**filtered)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal cls
        cls.__init__ = __init__
        cls = attrs.define(cls)
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@define
class Booking:
    id: int
    id_hash: str


booking = {"id": 1, "id_hash": "a3H33lk", "foo": "bar"}
b = Booking(**booking)
print(b)
# Booking(id=1, id_hash='a3H33lk')
```